# help finding DVD please

Tags: downloads

Can someone kindly provide me a link to buy the DVD, I can not for the life of me find it.  My DSL is slow, it will take a week to down load the package for my Laptop.  I donated money to ubuntu and can't find the page with the DVD to purchase.  An email link would be appreciated!

Comment: Search on Amazon.

Comment: Here ya go! https://www.amazon.com/Ubuntu-Linux-16-04-LTS-Bit/dp/B01EU8RG7M/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1513117032&sr=8-3&keywords=ubuntu+16.04

Comment: Looks like Canonical themselves went to USB sticks for purchase:  https://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=17

Answer (score 0):

Here is one site for the latest version
https://www.osdisc.com/products/linux/ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

If you have a public library or Linux user group<sup>1</sup> near you you should be able to get a copy of the Ubuntu installation image through them at little or no cost (though a small donation would be appropriate).

Just bring an

- empty DVD, either one rewritable or 2–3 non-rewritable ones in case something goes wrong, or
- any sufficiently large (≥2 GB) and common storage medium like a USB drive or a memory card.

Even if the library won't let you run programs that allows the creation of bootable USB media, you can still use it to transport the installation image file to your home computer and create the boot medium with your own computer.

---

<sup>1</sup> You should be able to find one, if it exists, with an online search for “Linux user group [name of your city or area]”.